# Convert quaternion to vector?

Tags: vectors, 3d, rotations, quaternions

Lets assume I have a rotation quaternion Q={1,1,1,0}, which represents a specific pointing direction, how can I extract this Vector(xyz) from it ? **Or, how can I determine a matrixs determinante**, because I already have a working solution that converts a quaternion to a matrix.

Comment: Your question is extremely unspecified. "Given four real numbers, how can I get three real numbers from it?" Lots of ways. *I would guess* that you mean for the vector to be related to the quaternion in a nice way. You really should tell us what that is. I myself am not aware of any natural correspondence between $\mathbb H$ and $\mathbb R^3$ that is worth mentioning.

Comment: Is "the weight" some universal constant? or is it related to the quaternion somehow? Are you talking about a *rotation* quaternion, and you want to find its axis? I guess not, if "the weight" turns out to be the length...

Comment: @rschwieb There is one very important application of quaternions that gives a certain subset of the quaternions a very tight correspondence with vectors of $\Bbb R^3$, and that is rotations. I don't know whether this one is such a quaternion, though...

Comment: @rschwieb : Yes, im talking about rotation quaternions, and Im asking you : How do I need the weight when converting to a 3d vector ?

Comment: @user7185318 And I'm answering you: I have no idea what conversion you are talking about. How do you convert four pennies into three? Hide one? melt them down and recast as three? *Are* you talking about recovering the axis of rotation from a quaternion???

Comment: @rschwieb : Are you talking about recovering the axis of rotation from a quaternion??? - i think so, because a rotation is nothing more then something that tells you **how** you are rotated , **in which direction** you are looking, and that can also be expressed as vector. Have a look at my edit(matrix)

Comment: Is {1,1,1,0} the quaternion 1+i+j?

Comment: *Lets assume I have a rotation quaternion Q={1,1,1,0}, which represents a specific pointing direction* **How** does it "represent a pointing direction"? Do you mean that the axis of rotation is around the vector $(1,1,1)$? If you mean that it represents the direction the camera is pointing after a rotation is applied, then that would be totally different.

Comment: @rschwieb :  **it represents the direction the camera is pointing after a rotation is applied**, you were right. But I havent understood how you convert them in your answer.

Comment: @user7185318 OK! that's progress...

Comment: It is [right here, in Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation#Quaternion-derived_rotation_matrix).

Answer (score 2):

*If* you are talking about recovering the direction vector for the axis from a rotation quaternion, and $q=a+bi+cj+dk$, then axis of rotation is the same direction as

$bi+cj+dk$, which would be the vector $(b,c,d)$ in $3$-space. If you need the unit vector in the direction you just normalize this, of course.

> **how can I determine a matrixs determinante,**

Every rotation matrix you would convert a quaternion to has determinant $1$, so... I have no idea where you're going with that.

> **a rotation is nothing more then something that tells you how you are rotated , in which direction you are looking, and that can also be expressed as vector.**

You seem to be having some difficulties expressing what you mean, and I think that this might stem from your belief that a quaternion represents a direction somehow. It doesn't, really. It represents a *transformation* (a rotation) of $3$-space in the context you are talking about.

What I *think* you're thinking of is this: given a camera pointing along (say) the $x$-axis, what direction will it be pointing after the transformation? That is a well-posed question, but it's not solely based on the quaternion, it's also based on the other input (the initial direction of the camera.)

In *that* case, then you're just going to have to take your initial camera direction expressed as a quaternion with real part zero (say $xi+yj+zk=v$) and see where it winds up pointing after $qvq^{-1}$.

---

Here is a concrete example based on the things you have said so far in the post and the comments. Suppose we have a camera pointing up the $z$ axis, and "**the quaternion (x=4,x=3,x=2,w=1)**" by which I guess you mean $4i+3j+2k+1$. We need to apply this quaternion to the vector for the camera's initial orientation $0i+0j+1k+0$.

Normally you would not deal with a rotation quaternion that is not unit length. But it turns out that for the purposes of rotation, doing $qxq^{-1}$ does the same thing whether or not you have normalized $q$. So we'll skip normalizing $q$.

The direct computation is $(4i+3j+2k+1)k(4i+3j+2k+1)^{-1}=\frac{22}{30}i+\frac{4}{30}j-\frac23 k$.

So the final direction of the camera is $(\frac{22}{30},\frac{4}{30},-\frac23)$

Comment: _a rotation is nothing more then something that tells you how you are rotated , in which direction you are looking, and that can also be expressed as vector._  Yes, so I was asking how can I represent the quaternion as vector. **How can I express/calculate the vector ?** So quaternion(abcd), vector=bcd ? **Yes, Im talking about recovering the direction vector, youre totally right !, but i havent understood, for example, lets take the quaternion (x=4,x=3,x=2,w=1) how you would now calculate the vector ?**

Comment: @user7185318 From your last comment in the post's thread, you seem to have confirmed that you are actually looking for the final direction of the line of sight of a rotated camera. Let's go with that. So my response is: the last paragraph of my answer tells you how to find the final line of sight of a camera given its initial line of sight. I will say (for the umpteenth time) that "the direction vector of a quaternion" does not make any sense to me. You can talk about the direction of the axis of rotation, or the direction an input vector after it is transformed by $q$

Comment: If you want to know what direction a camera points after it has been rotated by this quaternion **you are going to have to tell me where the camera is initially pointing.**

Comment: There appear to be lots of typos in your comment, but if you mean that you have a rotation quaternion $w+xi+yj+zk$, then its axis of rotation lies in the direction of $xi+yj+zk$. What more can I say?

Comment: initially pointing x=0 y=0 z=1

Comment: I cant understand your annotation. Whats x, whats y and whats z and how you do make them up from qx,qy,qz and qw

Comment: @user7185318 Is there something you don't understand about $q=w+xi+yj+zk$? That is the general form of a quaternion, where $w,x,y,z$ are real numbers. What is unclear here?

Comment: @user7185318 Anyhow, to see where $(0,0,1)$ ends up, you convert it to the quaternion $0i+0j+1k$. This is equal to $k$.  Now you just need to transform it with $q$ like this: $qkq^{-1}$. If you pick a $q$ and just perform the quaternion multiplication, you will wind up with another quaternion with the $w$ part equal to zero, and the remaining three numbers are the three coordinates of the direction the camera is pointing.

Comment: So, I just need to multiply it so that its w becomes zero?

Comment: @user7185318 no, you don't *need to multiply so that its w becomes zero*. You need to multiply $qkq^{-1}$ because that's what it means to apply the rotation $q$ to the 'quaternion-for-input-vector' $k$.